# MongoDB nested group?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to implement a nested group query in mongodb and I'm getting stuck trying to add the outer group by. Given the below (simplified) data document:

```
{
  "timestamp" : ISODate(),
  "category" : "movies",
  "term" : "my movie"
}
```

I'm trying to achieve a list of all categories and within the categories there should be the top number of terms. I would like my output to be something like this:

```
[
 { category: "movies", 
   terms: [ { term: "movie 1", total: 5000 }, { term: "movie 2", total: 200 } ... ]
 },
 { category: "sports", 
   terms: [ { term: "football 1", total: 4000 }, { term: "tennis 2", total: 250 } ... ]
 },
]
```

My 'inner group' is as shown below, and will get the top 5 for **all** categories:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match : { "timestamp": { $gt: ISODate("2014-08-27") } } },
    { $group : { _id :  "$term", total : { $sum : 1 } } },
    { $sort : { total : -1 } },
    { $limit: 5 }
]);

// Outputs:
{ "_id" : "movie 1", "total" : 943 }
{ "_id" : "movie 2", "total" : 752 }
```

How would I go about implementing the 'outer group'?

Additionally sometimes the above aggregation returns a null value (not all documents have a term value). How do I go about ignoring the null values?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 46):

You will need two groups in this case. The first group generates a stream of documents with one document per term and category:

```
 { $group : { 
      _id :  { 
        category: "$category",
        term: "$term",
      },
      total: { $sum : 1 } 
   }
 }
```

A second group will then merge all documents with the same term into one, using the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) operator to merge the categories into an array:

```
 { $group : { 
      _id :  "$_id.category",
      terms: { 
          $push: { 
              term:"$_id.term",
              total:"$total"
          }
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks! This has solved my problem, I've added `{ $sort : { total : -1 } }` inbetween the two groups to entire the most grouped terms are at the top, but I can't figure out how to limit the terms to say 5 per category. Adding `{ $limit: 6 }` inbetween the groups doesn't work. (I'm trying to do a top 5 terms per category query). thanks!

Comment: Helped me too! Magic!

Answer (score 7):

Query:

```
    db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
    {$match:{
        tipo: {$regex:"[A-Z]+"}
        }
    },
    {$group:
        { 
            _id:{
                codigo:"1",
                tipo:"$tipo",
            },
            total:{$sum:1}
        }
    },
    {$group:
        {
            _id:"$_id.codigo",
            tipos:
            {
                $push:
                {
                    tipo:"$_id.tipo",
                    total:"$total"
                }
            },
            totalGeneral:{$sum:"$total"}

        }

    }


]);
```

Response:

```
{
"_id" : "1",
"tipos" : [ 
    {
        "tipo" : "TIPO_01",
        "total" : 13.0
    }, 
    {
        "tipo" : "TIPO_02",
        "total" : 2479.0
    }, 
    {
        "tipo" : "TIPO_03",
        "total" : 12445.0
    }, 
    {
        "tipo" : "TIPO_04",
        "total" : 12445.0
    }, 
    {
        "tipo" : "TIPO_05",
        "total" : 21.0
    }, 
    {
        "tipo" : "TIPO_06",
        "total" : 21590.0
    }, 
    {
        "tipo" : "TIPO_07",
        "total" : 1065.0
    }, 
    {
        "tipo" : "TIPO_08",
        "total" : 562.0
    }
],
"totalGeneral" : 50620.0
```

}