# Mongodb limit array within aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm attempting to write a query to return the top X terms across each category - e.g. top 5, top 10 etc. Each term has an associated category, and based up on some help from another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666187/mongodb-nested-group) I've managed to get this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
    $group : { 
      _id :  { 
        category: "$uri.category",
        term: "$uri.term",
      },
      total: { $sum : 1 } 
    }
  },
  { $sort : { total : -1 } },
  { 
    $group : { 
        _id :  "$_id.category",
        terms: { 
            $push: { 
                term: "$_id.term",
                total: "$total"
            }
        }
     }
  }
]);
```

The above query does work, and returns data that looks something like this:

```
[
 { category: "movies", 
   terms: [ { term: "movie 1", total: 5000 }, { term: "movie 2", total: 200 } ... ]
 },
 { category: "sports", 
   terms: [ { term: "football 1", total: 4000 }, { term: "tennis 2", total: 250 } ... ]
 },
]
```

However I'm trying to limit the terms array to a fixed number i.e. 5 or 10 - this will correspond to the X number of searches per category. I've been trying various options such as adding `$slice` within the `$push` to reduce the terms array down with no success.

Can this be achieved using the aggregate framework, or should I look at another approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as of Mongodb 2.6, the ability to limit the size of an array using `$slice` or `$push` with the `.aggregate()` function/command is unsupported.
Here's the [feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6074) on the MongoDb issue tracker.

What I would do is output the aggregated result to an collection. Then update the collection.

## Example:

### Setup:

```
use test;
var rInt = function(x) {
    return 1 + ~~(Math.random() * x);
};
var rObj = function() {
    return {
        "timestamp": new Date(),
        "category": "movies" + rInt(5),
        "term": "my movie" + rInt(20)
    }
};
for (var i = 0, l = 100; i < l; i++) {
    db.al.insert(rObj());
}
```

### Aggregate query

```
db.al_out.drop();

db.al.aggregate([
  { 
    $group : { 
      _id :  { 
        category: "$category",
        term: "$term",
      },
      total: { $sum : 1 } 
    }
  },
  { $sort : { total : -1 } },
  { 
    $group : { 
        _id :  "$_id.category",
        terms: { 
            $push: { 
                term: "$_id.term",
                total: "$total"
            }
        }
     }
  }
  ,{ $out : "al_out" }  // output the documents to `db.al_out`
]);

// limit the size of terms to 3 elements.
db.al_out.update( {}, {
  $push : {
    terms : { 
      $each : [],
      $slice : 3 
    }
  }
}, {
  multi:true
});
```

### Result:

```
db.al_out.find();

{ "_id" : "movies1", "terms" : [ { "term" : "my movie7", "total" : 3 }, { "term" : "my movie6", "total" : 3 }, { "term" : "my movie17", "total" : 2 } ] }
{ "_id" : "movies2", "terms" : [ { "term" : "my movie3", "total" : 4 }, { "term" : "my movie11", "total" : 2 }, { "term" : "my movie2", "total" : 2 } ] }
{ "_id" : "movies4", "terms" : [ { "term" : "my movie9", "total" : 3 }, { "term" : "my movie1", "total" : 3 }, { "term" : "my movie7", "total" : 2 } ] }
{ "_id" : "movies3", "terms" : [ { "term" : "my movie19", "total" : 5 }, { "term" : "my movie8", "total" : 4 }, { "term" : "my movie14", "total" : 4 } ] }
{ "_id" : "movies5", "terms" : [ { "term" : "my movie7", "total" : 6 }, { "term" : "my movie17", "total" : 4 }, { "term" : "my movie3", "total" : 2 } ] }
```

Comment: there is no need to save an extra collection, u can use project and slice as Craig described in next answer.

Answer (score 8):

As of MongoDb version 3.1.6 you can now slice on the $project stage:

```
{
    $project: {
        terms: {
            $slice: ["$terms", 0, 10]
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to limit the number of items $pushed to 10.

Here's the issue:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6074

Answer (score 2):

I would add a $limit stage after the $sort and before the $group:

```
{ $limit : 5 },
```

This should limit the number of documents that are then being pushed into the array to 5. This will also serve to limit the total number of documents maintained in memory in the sort, which should improve overall performance:

> When a $sort immediately precedes a $limit in the pipeline, the $sort
>   operation only maintains the top n results as it progresses, where n
>   is the specified limit, and MongoDB only needs to store n items in
>   memory.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/

Comment: Although you are correct in that the `{ $limit : 5 }` does limit the results down to 5, I'm looking at getting the top 5 per category, and therefore would not solve the problem, as it limits across **all** categories.