# Grouping objects inside an array - MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregation

I am using a [training grades database](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/sample-data/sample-training/#sample-training-grades) from MongoDB. It is structured as follows.

```
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56d5f7eb604eb380b0d8d8fa"
    },
    "class_id": {
        "$numberDouble": "173"
    },
    "scores": [
        {
            "score": {
                "$numberDouble": "19.81430597438296"
            },
            "type": "exam"
        },
        {
            "score": {
                "$numberDouble": "16.851404299968642"
            },
            "type": "quiz"
        },
        {
            "score": {
                "$numberDouble": "60.108751761488186"
            },
            "type": "homework"
        },
        {
            "score": {
                "$numberDouble": "22.886167083915776"
            },
            "type": "homework"
        }
    ],
    "student_id": {
        "$numberDouble": "4"
    }
}
```

I am trying to run aggregation which returns all documents grouped first by class_id and then by student_id with all homework scores like the following.

```
{
   class_id: 3,
   all_scores: [
      {
         student_id: 110, 
         scores : [
            {
               type: "homework", 
               score: 89.98
            },
            {
               type: "homework", 
               score: 90.98
            },
         ]
      },
      {
         student_id:190, 
         scores : [
            {
               type: "homework", 
               score: 18.98
            },
            {
               type: "homework", 
               score: 99.98
            },
         ]
      },
   ]
}
```

I am running the following aggregation function.

```
[
  {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$scores'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'scores.type': 'homework'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$class_id', 
      'scores': {
        '$push': {
          'type': '$scores.type', 
          'score': '$scores.score', 
          'student_id': '$student_id'
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But it is returning the following result:

```
{
   _id: 3, 
   scores: [
      {
         "type": "homework",
         "score": 89.98, 
         "student_id": 110
      }, 
      {
         "type": "homework",
         "score": 90.98, 
         "student_id": 110
      }, 
      {
         "type": "homework",
         "score": 18.98, 
         "student_id": 190
      }, 
      {
         "type": "homework",
         "score": 99.98, 
         "student_id": 190
      },
   ]
}
```

If even if there are multiple objects in the scores array, it is not combining them with the student_id group and shows them separate. I am not sure of what I should add to the aggregation. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Would this result help: https://mongoplayground.net/p/3PRZB8lXMoB
It's not exactly in the format you wanted but it's close.

Comment: So I have gotten that result already by using a much simpler query. I am trying to get it exactly like described in the question. But good suggestion tho!

Comment: Please see my answer, I'll edit it if explanation is required.

Answer (score 1):

[Mongo Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7Vb9FK0jUoM)

I think this is the precise format you wanted.

The aggregation pipeline:

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$scores"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "scores.type": "homework"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "class_id": "$class_id",
        "student_id": "$student_id"
      },
      "scores": {
        "$push": {
          "type": "$scores.type",
          "score": "$scores.score"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.class_id",
      all_scores: {
        $push: {
          "student_id": "$_id.student_id",
          scores: "$scores"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      class_id: "$_id",
      all_scores: "$all_scores"
    }
  }
]
```

The first two stages of the pipeline I guess are simply to filter out the non-homework documents.

To perform a "nested grouping" of sorts, where not only does the data have an outer grouping over `class_id` but an inner grouping in the `scores` over `student_id`, first we group the data in the first `$group` stage over *both* those fields, much like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25667256/6718353).

The `scores` array in each document here will be the same as the arrays we need in each inner grouping (over `student_id`), so, now we can just group by the `class_name` (in the `_id` object after the result of the first group stage) and add the `student_id` along with the `scores` in each object to push in the `all_scores` array. Then the final `$project` stage is pretty trivial, just to get it in the format that we want.

Comment: So I ran that but now each class id only contains one student object. It should contain multiple.

Comment: You sure? If you check my link, it has multiple students in one document.

Comment: Oh My God! That worked like a charm! Thank you alot brother!

Comment: Happy to help, bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Try With this Aggregate Query,

```
[
  {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$scores'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'scores.type': 'homework'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {class_id:'$class_id',
              student_id:'$student_id'}, 
      'scores': {
        '$push': {
          'type': '$scores.type', 
          'score': '$scores.score'
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: But that would group it by student_id first. I want to group it by class_id first.

Comment: Please check Again I was updated my answer as you want.

Comment: Your solution does work but only partially. While it does group class_id and student_id together, it does not group student_id separately. I need to have one document for each class and within each class an array of all students. And within each student in that class, an array of their scores of type specified.